# XAML Pages in VS 2012 not displaying

Tags: xaml, windows-8

When I try to look at any *.xaml page, I see instead an err msg, "*System.UnauthorizedAccessException
Error 5: Access is denied : 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'*"

Is it simply a matter of adding '**C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll**' to my path, or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a permissions issue:  the XAML designer is unable to access the reference assemblies.  One of my colleagues posted a straightforward solution in an answer to the following MSDN Forums inquiry:

> [VS 2012 RC XAML Designer Crashes with Access Denied](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/a40977f2-c7e6-41dd-921d-dc9d9aed01eb/)

Comment: There it says, "Launch a command prompt as an Administrator." but I don't know how to do that. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/run-a-command-as-administrator-from-the-windows-vista-run-box/ has some ideas, but they don't work...

Comment: Ah: Windows key + E; enter shell:system, <Enter>, navigate to cmd.exe, right-click, Run as Administrator

Comment: Also, on the Start screen, you can type cmd to find the command prompt, right-click it, and select Run as Administrator from the App Bar at the bottom of the screen.